# Unable to find Hibernate Tools in Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1 after installation of plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to install Hibernate Tools plugin in my Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1 version, installation completes without any error but in am neither able to see Hibernate perspective nor I am getting options to reverse engineer hibernate classes. 
I have tried following without success:

1. Using Install new software option..., update using site link -> [Link](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/luna/)
2. Install Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio (Luna) 8.0.0.CR1 from Eclipse Marketplace
3. Download zip archive update from jboss developer tools site.

Did someone succeeded with Hibernate tools configuration in STS 3.6.1 Release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this path :

```
Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Hibernate
```

You will be able to see the perspective !

Comment: I have checked but not able to see Perspective here, however in the meantime, I have re-downloaded the STS and installed plugin from scratch, this time it shown the perspective but still there are so many error regarding logger etc. shown in my Error window. trying to remove them one by one. but i have to say it is very time consuming. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Look for help->About Spring Tool Suite

You know the eclipse version now

Version: 3.6.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201408250824
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)

You need JBoss Tool in some version

http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/overview.html
4.1.2.Final is the stable version for Kepler there:

From this link there is hint that Help > Eclipse Marketplace

From the new window search for  JBoss Tools (Kepler)
Download that and restart,

Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Hibernate   {will work}